# Where does f.lux install itself?

Tags: applications

I'm really puzzled here.  I just installed a new copy of Sierra on another partition, and as part of setting it up I double-clicked on my saved copy of f.lux that I keep in my "system rebuild" folder.  It asked me if I wanted to move it into Applications so I said yes, not thinking that it literally meant *move* and not copy, so it disappeared from my rebuild folder.  I figured it would now be in Applications, but it's not!

Even after a reboot, f/lux is running but it's not in Applications.  So where the heck did it put itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd presume it'd be in /Applications or ~/Applications, the latter being within your home directory?

You can find where the process is by sampling it in Activity Monitor.

1. In Activity Monitor's CPU tab, find and select f.lux.
2. From the gear menu, choose Sample Process.

   [image]
3. Observe the path to the process.

   [image]

Comment: Of course!  ~/Applications.  I completely forgot there even WAS a user-space applications folder.  Thanks much, and also for the Activity Monitor tip.  Hadn't thought of that one.